rhub::rhub_check() fails for [VM] macos-arm64
I'm running another final (definitely final this time) check ahead of submitting a new version of a package to CRAN using rhub::rhub_check() in which I selected the usual:

1 [VM]  linux
2 [VM]  macos
3 [VM]  macos-arm64
4 [VM]  windows

Unlike all previous occasions, the check fails on macos-arm64, with the following output

Dependency resolution
Error in dyn.load(dll_file) :
unable to load shared object '/private/var/folders/g6/rgtlsw6n123b0gt5483s5_cm0000gn/T/RtmpcqvXU5/file25eb4efccd88/ps/libs//ps.so':
dlopen(/private/var/folders/g6/rgtlsw6n123b0gt5483s5_cm0000gn/T/RtmpcqvXU5/file25eb4efccd88/ps/libs//ps.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '_ps__list_apps'
Calls:  ... load_private_packages -> load_private_package -> dyn.load
Execution halted
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I'm confused because the checks worked fine last week and I've made only minor changes to some code examples.
GitHub Actions announcements at https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/macos/macos-14-Readme.md suggest that some features (e.g., Node.js-v16, XCode 14 and 16 were removed a little while ago, and macOS 15 (Sequoia) is now available). But I cannot see how those could make any difference to my rhub_check().
Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Or that I should now be taking into account?
Or should I just ignore the "failure", rerun rhub::rhub_check() without 3 macos-arm64, and submit to CRAN anyway?

do you mind sharing the link to the repository? for example, for my redatam pkg I had to install libpng, which is not required by my package, but otherwise the checks fail with mac-14 (arm64)

Happy to:
https://github.com/WinzarH/LikertMakeR

Update:
Now, with no change at all to the package on GitHub, the rhub::rhub_check() passes without a problem. It passed last week. It didn't for three days. Now it passes again.
As Shakespeare (in Love) says, "It's a mystery!"
Thanks to @pachadotdev for his consideration (you took me down an interesting path. Fruitless, but still interesting.)

the same issue reappeared https://github.com/r-lib/actions/issues/948#issuecomment-2496102989
